# fullCalendar - preserve onClick bindings on events divs after moving them out of the #calendar div

Tags: javascript, click, fullcalendar

When I move a fullCalendar event's div out of its container div or even out of the #calendar div (using .appendTo(), .append(), .insertBefore(), or even .clone(true, true).insertBefore() ... ), it loses its onClick binding. That is to say my callback (initially passed to the fullCalendar constructor) doesn't fire anymore. I hope I didn't make an obvious mistake, I'm new to javascript and fullCalendar.

interesting fact: in chrome dev tools, moving the events anywhere in the dom (manually click an drag them around) preserves their bindings. because of that I thought it'd be a piece of cake to make a custom listView, but moving the event divs programmatically does erase the onClick events every time. (if anyone knows the exact reason for the dev tools behavior I'm very curious to see if I can replicate this behavior with code)

the html structure is:

```
<div id="calendar" … >
<div class="fc-content" … >
    <table class="fc-view fc-view-month fc-grid"> … </table> //day header, moved by code
    <div … >... </div>     //this is the event container, also moved by the code below
    <div class="fc-view fc-view-basicDay fc-grid" ... >
        <table class="fc-view fc-view-month fc-grid"> … </table> //normal day header, intact
        <div … > ... </div>     //normal event container, intact
```

here is the javascript that moves the table (day header) and event container divs out:

```
var fcViewBasicDay = $('.fc-view.fc-view-basicDay.fc-grid');

var table = fcViewBasicDay.children(".fc-border-separate");// table (day header)
table.clone(true).insertBefore(fcViewBasicDay);

var event_container = table.next(); //event container div
event_container.clone(true, true).insertBefore(fcViewBasicDay);
```

other interesting fact: if I change the last line -> I clone the original event div and append it in its original place, and move the real one out, like this:

```
event1_moved.insertBefore(fcViewBasicDay); //inserting the "real div event"
event1_moved.clone(true, true).appendTo(fcViewBasicDay); //keeping a cloned one in place of the real
```

...then fullCalendar doesn't refresh with new events when I press next day -- it refreshes with the same event on the next day.

if I just move it without replacing, the page loads forever (infinite loop?). it's as if cloning that div erases some kind of "markor" recognized by fullCalendar.

P.S. I am checking this page often, tell me if need more information.

Comment: Why would you move something out of the div and expect it to still work?  Why are you moving events at all?  I am not following what you are doing at all.

Comment: Hi, yes, the reason I am moving divs is to make a listview, which is not built-in FC. In general I'm used to moving html elements with .appendTo() -- and this always keeps their jquery bindings; .clone(true).appendTo() is also supposed to keep all bindings. the regular onclick handler is also not defined. So I'm at a loss here, where is that click handler held? ... and can I access it from outside the source, to re-bind it to my moved divs.